# Struggling with database design

Tags: database

I am looking top create a database and I am struggling to get my head around how i should design it.

The database will store the details of each customer, keep track of tasks and their details and assign tasks to various customers.

The problem is each customer can have many tasks assigned to them and the same task can also be assigned to many customers.

I have been out of touch with databases for a while and am struggling with this simple many to many relationship problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say task, do you mean a task type (definition)? The difference being a task type is a definition of what the task entails and it's details while a task is an actual instruction to do something, and can be completed and archived, etc... For example, LoadingGoods is a task definition, while LoadingGoods-0023 is a task assigned to customer X on 1st of feb 12:30pm. In your case, will many customers be assigned an instance of task definition or each customer will have their own instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should think about a mapping table:

```
So, tables:

Customers          Tasks          CustTasks
-------------------------------------------
CustomerID         TaskID         ID
CustomerName       Description    CustomerID
CustomerAddress                   TaskID 
etc...
```

So customer 1 with 2 tasks assigned will have 2 rows in the CustTasks table.

```
ID  CustomerID   TaskID
1   1            4
2   1            7
```

Likewise, it'll allow for the same task to be assigned to many customers.